# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setOnClickListener... ' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I've wrote lines of code from my previous project that loads the gallery when clicking on the profile picture. I copied pasted the code from that project to here making appropriate changes expecting to work (since it works perfectly on the other app). But I get Null Pointer Exception.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.kujinn.meetup.Settings.onCreateView(Settings.java:78)
```

I tried seeing if I accidently used the same id twice or if I was using the wrong view but nothing seemed to be out of place.

Java Code:

```
   private CircleImageView profileImage
   profileImage = (CircleImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_image);
   profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //If version is greater than Marshmallow, User Permissions in required
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

                    //Display message that user has denied permission
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);

                    } else{

                        CropImage.activity()
                                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                                .start(getActivity());
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

XML code

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_profile_toolbar">

 </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

Any help would be greatly appreciated ~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations like this, there may be two scenarios. It’s either you are instantiating your CircleImageView before setting the content view or you are not instantiating the CircleImageView correctly. Make sure your ‘setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)’ comes before you assign the profileImage. The null pointer exception literally means that the parent layout has not been set and yet you are calling a component on it. This will definitely point to a null.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use viewBinding to avoid null reference: Video link is below and not sponsored. Actually, View binding is a feature that allows you to more easily write code that interacts with views. Once view binding is enabled in a module, it generates a binding class for each XML layout file present in that module. An instance of a binding class contains direct references to all views that have an ID in the corresponding layout. In most cases, view binding replaces findViewById.

View binding has important advantages over using findViewById: [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSg3A-CQnsU&feature=youtu.be)